# What is the difference between assigning a variable value with functionName() and just functionName?

Tags: javascript, debouncing

```
const heightOutput = document.querySelector('#height');
const widthOutput = document.querySelector('#width');

function reportWindowSize() {
  heightOutput.textContent = window.innerHeight;
  widthOutput.textContent = window.innerWidth;
}

window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```

why not
`window.onresize = reportWindowSize()`
?
it's function call, I want to trigger it. but when I add the () it's not working.

Comment: When you do `window.onresize = ...`, you give it a function. Then, the browser will take care of calling it when needed. If you pass it `reportWindowSize()`, you are passing it the result of that function (`undefined`). So it can't call anything. It would just be like doing `var result = myFunc(); window.onresize = result;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the statement as `reportWindowSize()`, what this does is it invokes the function `reportWindowSize`. After the invocation, it returns some value which in this case is `undefined`. So, `window.onresize` will be assigned value `undefined`.

Now, let's talk about `window.onresize`. It is an event handler that gets triggered
when certain events occur, in this case when window size is changed. More on events: [Events API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

What this means is, when a window is resized some native code will call the handler `window.onresize` like this `window.onresize()`. If it is `undefined` then it won't work. It must be a function, so we either pass a reference of a function to it, which is exactly what you are doing or pass function value. Passing reference won't call the function but instead point it to the function you are passing. And finally, when the event is triggered the function `reportWindowSize` gets called.

Some resources that might be helpful:

- [Functions in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)
- [First-class Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function)